# Android - Get absolute file path from uri, picked from Downloads

Tags: android, filepath, download-manager, file-uri

I am trying to get the absolute file path from the uri. But can't get it for the files downloaded with some download manager.

For example, I have downloaded an audio and stored it in `/storage/emulated/0/MIUI/.ringtone/Our Street (30-secs version)_&_7f2f552b-b5b8-41a0-94de-4b3b065b7c00.mp3`. If I pick this file from `Downloads` section of file picker I got the following uri `content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/19` and I can not calculate the absolute path from this uri.

But if I pick the file from original directory i.e `/storage/emulated/0/MIUI/.ringtone/` I got this uri `content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary%3AMIUI%2F.ringtone%2FOur%20Street%20(30-secs%20version)_%26_7f2f552b-b5b8-41a0-94de-4b3b065b7c00.mp3` and I can get the absolute file path from this url.

**How could I get the absolute file path while picked from `Downloads`?**

I am opening file picker using following code:

```
Intent chooseFile = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
chooseFile.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
chooseFile.setType("*/*");
chooseFile.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE,false);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(chooseFile, "Select Audio"), PICK_AUDIO_RESULT_CODE);
```

For parsing absolute file path from uri I'm using following code:

```
final String id = DocumentsContract.getDocumentId(uri);

final Uri contentUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(
        Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads"), Long.valueOf(id)
);

Cursor cursor = null;
final String column = "_data";
final String[] projection = {column};

try {
    cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection,
            selection, selectionArgs, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        final int index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(column);
        return cursor.getString(index);
    }
} finally {
    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.close();
}
return null;
```

Comment: `am trying to get the absolute file path from the uri` You should not try to do so. If you pick an uri you can use the uri as is. No need for a path. Please tell why you would.

Comment: `Uri.parse("content://downloads/public_downloads")` Why are you hard coding? You can get all that from the picked uri to begin with.

Comment: I need the  absolute path to execute some command using ffmpeg

Comment: Well that provider will not give you a path in .DATA column. Only .DISPLAY_NAME and such. Maybe on an old Android version but not for instance on Android Q.

Comment: any suggestion for how to get things working?

Comment: First tell Android version of used device(s).

Comment: Android 10, poco x3